# How can you update an array with knockout?

Tags: knockout.js, d3.js

I have an array that is defining a bar graph in D3.

```
var data = [4, 3];
```

I want to update the values in data by utilizing knockout. Is there an easy way to do this or a better set up that could be used?

```
data[0] = (data-bind="value: children().length");
```

This did not work and made the graph disappear, which I'm assuming means it is not allowed. I'm new to both d3 and ko.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using knockout's data-bind syntax in javascript land. Data-bind is to be used as an HTML attribute as in [these examples](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-syntax.html) and not in JS land.

The graph may have disappeared because the code above would have broken the javascript interpreter (it is not valid javascript syntax) before the interpreter could get to the d3 code.

To have knockout handle the binding between javascript objects check out [observables](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html) and how their subscribe function works.